# What is an expression you can use for when you're getting close to the end of a time-sensitive project?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I want to say something like,

> I am getting down to the chopping block

but that means more like, I am deciding who to keep and who not to, it conveys being harshly decisive.

That's not quite the point. The point is that as you approach the final hour, things get tense, yet exciting.

Is there a similarly colourful expression of the form, "I am getting into/down to...." ?

Comment: I soon as I wrote this, it occurred to me that "the midnight hour" is not a bad expression.

Comment: Or “burning my last candle”

Comment: When NASA Jet Propulsion Laboratory (JPL) landed the Mars Science Laboratory (Curiosity rover) on Mars, the entry descent and landing (EDL) phase was nicknamed "7 minutes of terror".  An an engineer, I've found this reference useful on many occasions to describe a time-sensitive critical point of a project.  But, it's not a general expression, and also not the __end__ of the project.  The Cassini space probe's end was dubbed its _grand finale_, but that just means _the end_ rather than _getting close to the end_, and it's more inevitable than urgent, but it was tense and exciting!

Comment: Entirely not colourful, but still idomatic: 'rapidly approaching the deadline'.

Comment: Peter, can you say whether your people are happy, or worried to be approaching their deadline?

What research have you done; what suggestions have you rejected and why, other than "I am getting down to the chopping block"?

FYI that might to you mean "I am deciding who to keep and who not to…" and "convey being harshly decisive" and in 60 years of listening I never once heard a phrase close to that meaning, or that conveyance.

Again, what research have you done?

Comment: Who are you saying it to? People on the project or superiors about the project? Are you inspiring urgency or conveying your commitment to success to a third party?

Comment: When you say "end", you mean "deadline", right? I'm just wondering whether you might mean "completion", like as if you're finishing a project early and you're excited to finish it.

Comment: I like **"I'm getting down to bedrock"** for this. To me it invokes the beginning of the end as you are not going below the bedrock, but you may still need to tidy everything up and finish. [Bedrock](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+down+to+bedrock)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the idiom *(be) in/on the home stretch*. I believe it is used as *home straight* also in the UK.

> In the midst of the final portion of an activity, project, competition, etc. Likened to the straightaway at the end of a race. 
>  *The bulk of the work is behind us—we're in the home stretch now!* 
> [idioms.thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+home+stretch)

The analogy comes from horse racing, and *home stretch* is a term used in baseball also.

Comment: I'm not sure this necessarily always includes the tension/excitement aspect? It can sometimes be more a sense of relief at coming to the end of a long journey/project/etc.

Comment: Similar to this would be: "*on the last leg*".  Note that both of these imply a project ending on schedule with no extra work required and no tension about whether or not it'll be done in time.  If you *want* to imply that extra effort and anxiety, I'd go with Weather Vane's answer of "crunch time" instead.

Comment: I agree with @Mohirl, "on the home stretch" implies relief, more along the lines of "we're almost done (and then we won't have to worry about it anymore)", whereas the other answer's "it's crunch time" has connotations more along the lines of "we're almost out of time (so we might not make it in time and need to work harder)", which I think is closer to what the asker wanted.

Comment: Re home straight -  that sounds idiomatic to my UK ears. According to https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/home_straight it’s an athletics reference rather than horse racing.  Mm . And the athletics track is what comes to my mind reading the phrase. Home stretch sound a bit strange to me!

Comment: Agreed with @Mohirl and @ Hearth — to my ear as a native UK speaker, this definitely doesn’t fit what the OP asks for.  The *home stretch* doesn’t mean the part where the tension rises — on the contrary, it means the next stage, where the tension is *dissipating* because someone is becoming confident of success.  In @ ermanen’s example of a football match, I would expect it to be used like *Arsenal are coming into the home stretch now*, meaning that Arsenal are ahead and the other team are unlikely to recover.  I wouldn’t expect *home stretch* to be used while the match is tight.

Answer (score 37):

You can say

> It's **crunch** time.
> It's coming to the **crunch**.

[Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/crunch+time) has

> **crunch time**
>
> A critical period of time characterized by a heightened pressure to succeed, usually at or near the end of a given situation or undertaking.
>
> A period when pressure to succeed is great, often toward the end of an undertaking.
>
> *Okay, we've got two minutes to tie the game—it's crunch time, guys!*

---

Another suggestion is

> We are coming to the **moment of truth**.

[Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/moment+of+truth) says

> The moment or point at which some critical and decisive event, action, or test will occur.
>
> *We've been working on a prototype of this device for months. Now comes the moment of truth, when we test it in a real-world environment.*

Comment: I like _crunch_ a lot more than _moment of truth_ (which conveys no sense of time-sensitivity to me.)

Comment: To me, crunch time is a period of time (for example the last month of a large project). The moment of truth is very different; it truly is a _moment_, the instant that defines success or failure. When crunch time ends  and it's time to "flip the switch" to turn the system on and see if it works or not, that's the moment of truth

Comment: I think *Crunch Time* works better in some respects than *Home Stretch.*  *Crunch time* implies that there will  be *nose to the grindstone* attentiveness to the project while crucial elements are resolved.  *Crunch time* is not necessarily associated with the end of a project.  If unexpected issues arise, crunch time can occur in the middle of a project.  *Home stretch*, on the other hand, almost always refers to the end of something.  Maybe my perception of the phrase is personal, but *home stretch* indicates one may coast to the finish.  *Home Stretch* is the fresh air after *Crunch Time.*

Comment: @EllieK Sounds like we need a new term, *crunch stretch*!

Comment: "It's Showtime" also comes to mind.

Comment: +1 for crunch time. -1 for moment of truth.

Answer (score 24):

An idiomatic expression for that would be: [down to the wire](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/down--to--the--wire).

Were you to say, "I'm really taking it down to the wire," you'd be saying that you're getting quite close to the deadline, even possibly ill-advisably close or dangerously close -- so close that you very well may not get it done in time, especially if any unforeseen problem or unforeseen delay arises, as "*taking it down to the wire*" means you're leaving yourself no extra time at all for anything except exactly what you expect needs to be done at the fastest pace you're estimated capable of doing it in, which it's quite possible is an overestimation, another common cause of people *taking it down to the wire* missing their deadlines and why *taking it down to the wire* is so close to the end of a time-sensitive project that it can even end up being *too* close.

Comment: I've only ever heard this as "coming down to the wire".

Comment: Just to be clear, "taking" is not a crucial part of the idiom. You could also say, like, "We're really *down to the wire* on this project" or something like "These delays have **brought** us *down to the wire*."

Answer (score 12):

> What is an expression you can use for when you're getting close to the end of a time-sensitive project?

^ This is a bit ambiguous. Are you close to the end of the project or close to the end of the time constraint?

---

If you are at the end of the time constraint then:

> I am in the **eleventh hour**

[Eleventh hour](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eleventh%20hour)

> : the latest possible time before it is too late
> // still making changes at the eleventh hour

---

If you are close to completing the project then:

> I can see the light at the end of the tunnel

[A light at the end of the tunnel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20light%20at%20the%20end%20of%20the%20tunnel)

> : a reason to believe that a bad situation will end soon or that a long and difficult job will be finished soon
> // They are falling deeper into debt, and there is no light at the end of the tunnel.
> // The work on our house has been going on for months, but we're finally starting to see a light at the end of the tunnel.

---

If both then:

> I am in the eleventh hour but can see a light at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: A quite useful idiom - and also [the sequel to The 7th Guest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_11th_Hour_(video_game)) ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You could use an expression from horse racing...

> I am getting into the final furlong.

Where the final [furlong](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/furlong) is the last ⅛ mile (0.2 kilometer) up to the finish line...where things get tense, yet exciting.

Comment: In the U.S., a more common expression is ["the home stretch"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homestretch) (also from horse racing).

Comment: There are probably many other racing-related metaphors you could use (whether for athletes, horses, or cars), e.g. ‘_entering the final straight_’, or ‘_the last lap_’, or ‘approaching the wire_’, or ‘_the end is in sight_’.

Comment: Or... the _bell lap_

Comment: And *nearing the finish line*.

Answer (score 2):

**It’s showtime.**  The preparations and rehearsals are over. It’s time to put your work in front of the paying  audience.

This concept of *putting on a show* is also used in the term **show stopper**. As in: “We’ve still got lots of problems, but no show stoppers.  Let’s go ahead with the release”.

Comment: I'll mention that showstopper is a contranym, a word that is its own antonym - it can indicate either a catastrophic problem, or something incredibly positive. Its original use was a positive one, indicating a theatrical performance that received prolonged applause, literally stopping the show and preventing it from proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

***"Squeaky bum time"***

This is my personal favourite. Possibly invented by former Manchester United boss Sir Alex Ferguson. It has also been used in Doctor Who. It fits perfectly the usage you are after. Time is running out, things are getting tense.

Answer (score 1):

Another *colorful* idiomatic expression is ***down to the short strokes*** as it appears to be an allusion to painting. A painter starts painting on a clean canvas using large or broad strokes of the brush; but as the painting progresses, the strokes become shorter and finer where the painter fill the details into the painting. It reminds me of Bob Ross where he paints twigs and sticks at the end of his paintings, whether on the happy trees or within the nature that you can see in almost all his paintings.

*[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/down_to_the_short_strokes)* also adds that it can be an allusion to golf or swimming; and provides the etymology and the definition as below:

> **Etymology:** Possibly an allusion to painting, in which a painter typically finishes a work with short, careful, finishing strokes of the paint brush, or to golf, in which a player concludes each hole by making short strokes with a putter. In swimming competition, as a swimmer nearly reaches a wall to turn or to finish, the competitor might take a shorter stroke to start the turn smoothly, or to finish faster.
>
> **Adjective** 
> **down to the short strokes** 
> (*idiomatic*) In the final steps or decisive phase of an undertaking, especially one which has been lengthy or laborious.

Answer (score 1):

My personal favourite: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/593667

> **Down to the wire**
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down-to-the-wire
> full of suspense
> especially : unsettled until the very end
>
> https://knowyourphrase.com/down-to-the-wire
> The phrase down to the wire means that there is a tense situation in a competition where the outcome is only clear at or near the end.
>
> > It’s believed this expression originates from horse racing, but why? Because in horse races, a wire was often hung across the finish line in order to help determine the winner. This was especially useful in races that were very close towards the end. Thus, as the riders approached the finish line, they could be described as coming down to the wire, quite literally.

Different subject domains and the urgency or likelihood of meeting the deadline will lend themselves to different phrases.

I like [*It's **crunch time***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/593659) however this implies a more *imminent* and yet *less predictable* deadline, which is similar to *being on the chopping block*.

- *crunch* and *chop* are great verbs if you want to emphasise risk of failure to meet the deadline.
- *crunch time* is also used to describe scenarios of high pressure that might not necessarily be associated with a deadline, it is more of a statement of the current situation and less about what might be coming.

To help put some of these phrases into context, I am guilty of over-using pep talks like this as we approach the end of a milestone or a competitive sport:

> It's **crunch time** people! We're in the **final straight** but I don't want this one to **come down to the wire**!

*in the [Eleventh Hour](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/593714)* is similar to the previous phrases, still with a *close* but not *literally fixed* deadline, without the same immediacy.

- The butcher is probably not going to wait a whole hour before *chopping*...

***moment of truth*** and [It’s showtime](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/593692) both allude to a *reveal*, which is still *exciting* and inspires *anticipation* but is *past* or *present* tense of the deadline, so less about the preparation or the amount of time that is left.

I am sure there are other *idioms* that apply to this scenario but there are many *metaphors* at our disposal. The problem with a metaphor is that you need to be aware of your audience and be careful to use a comparison that the target audience is likely to be able to relate to.

When using a technical domain reference (like *[down to the short strokes](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/593707)*) the message can be ambiguous to a reader who does not understand the domain, even if the reader can surmise the intent based on the common setup ***down to XXXX***, the emphasis that you are trying to make about *excitement* and *tension* can be easily lost.

Sporting references are similar except that they tend to be geographically or culturally constrained or will have slightly different variations that might make it hard for the reader to relate to. The examples offered by [@Davislor](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/593726) highlight some of these variations.

Overall it would appear that *horse racing* analogies are over represented in this scenario, but that is likely due to it being a relative standard sport across many English speaking regions that have traditionally involved all castes and classes of society in different ways for many centuries. So its generally a safer sporting reference to use as there is a high chance that an English reader would be able to relate to it.

Answer (score 0):

Merriam-Webster defines [buzzer-beater](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buzzer-beater) as:

> a shot successfully made just before a buzzer or horn sounds to signal the end of a period
>
> *especially* : such a shot made to win a game just before the final buzzer or horn sounds

A closely-related expression is **at the buzzer**.

Some of many other metaphors from sports: **bottom of the ninth** (from baseball), **inside the two-minute warning** (American football), **stoppage time** (soccer), **at the death** (primarily British—American soccer fans seem familiar with it from British announcers, but be careful with this one), **sudden death** (many sports, but again, be careful that this is clear in context) or **match point** (tennis).

Answer (score 0):

One other option is "getting into the short rows." This comes from farming; if you are plowing a field that is at all irregular, the last few rows will be shorter than the bulk of them. It's a good metaphor for all the little tasks that often have to be done as a project is wrapped up, and so it's not the same as "crunch time", which suggests that central tasks are being worked on right up to the end.

I would also distinguish "crunch time" from "the home stretch". The former has a stronger sense of pressure (after all, the word "crunch" is right there in the expression). The latter, for many people, focuses on being close enough to the end that you know you will finish. Of course, in a horse race that is a very high-pressure time since you want to win the race, not just finish, and maybe you're not even leading. But in practice, people often talk about being in the home stretch when a lot of the risky parts are done and they are feeling more confident.